# When creating a variable in a JavaScript object, how does the code know where to add the new variable?

Tags: javascript, object

I'm working through a JavaScript course and I'm curious how the code know to include an `age` value above the object properties when I log it out to console? Here is the code from the lesson:

```
var john = {
    name: 'John',
    lastName: 'Smith',
    yearOfBirth: 1990,
    job: 'teacher',
    isMarried: false,
    family: ['Jane', 'Mark', 'Bob'],
    calculateAge: function() {
        this.age = 2016 - this.yearOfBirth;
   }
};

john.calculateAge();
console.log(john);
```

If I understand correctly, I create an `age` variable in this line:

```
this.age = 2016 - this.yearOfBirth;
```

When I look in my console, the `age` property and its value are stated above the object properties. What determines this presentation?

Comment: `age` is not a variable, it's a property.

Comment: Btw, we have 2017 :-)

Comment: I know, the course was released in 2016 and I'm following along to make sure I understand the principle first. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `age` variable in your example. This line:

```
this.age = 2016 - this.yearOfBirth;
```

adds a property `age` to an object referenced by `john` variable.

And object properties **are not ordered**. It means that inside the program the `age` property is not above all others. It also means that you **cannot be sure** that when using iterative constructions like `for..in` the `age` will be at the top.

> When I look in my console, the age variable and its value are stated
>   above the object properties.

If you use `console.log` to show the object it uses formatting that orders keys by alphabet. Try using different name, for example, `xge` and you will see that it will be outputted close to the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see the below snippet you are creating the variable age and adding it as a property of this

```js
var john = {
 name: 'John',
 lastName: 'Smith',
 yearOfBirth: 1990,
 job: 'teacher',
 isMarried: false,
 family: ['Jane', 'Mark', 'Bob'],
 calculateAge: function() {
 console.log('#1', this);
 this.age = 2016 - this.yearOfBirth;
 console.log('#2', this);
 }
};

john.calculateAge();
console.log(john);
```

Comment: Thanks, I understood that. When I log this to console, it shows me the new `age` variable above the object properties. Is that just how the `age` variable is logged by default?

Comment: in the #1 output it is not logged, after adding it to this it would be logged every time